# Non-Differentiability of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

> $$f(z)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \frac{z^5}{\vert z^4\vert} &, z\neq 0 \\
> 0 &, z=0\end{array}\right.$$
>   Proof that this function is not differentiable in $z_0=0$, but partial differentiable. Also proof that the Cauchy-Riemann differential equations are valid. Why this isn't a contradiction?

So we defined the differentiability with this:

*Let $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ a domain and $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ a function with $z_0\in G$. f is called differentiable if $\exists \Delta:G\to\mathbb{C}$ so that:*

1. $f(z)=f(z_0)+(z-z_0)\Delta(z)\,\forall z\in G$
2. $\Delta$ *is continuous in $z_0$*.

So I have to proof the differentiability for $z_0=0$. There I get for the first condition:
$$f(z)=0+z\cdot \Delta(z)$$

Therefore $\Delta(z)$ has to be 0. But now $\Delta$ is continuous and that can't be right.

The CR-DE are valid, because $f_x(0)=0=f_y(0)$. The differentiability in $\mathbb{R}$ I can proof with the calculation of an existing limit $$\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$.

Where are my mistakes? Or do you have any hints for the rest of my attempts?

Comment: How did you deduce $\Delta(z) = 0$? Dividing $f(z)$ by $z$, I get something else.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. Yeah you're right there is a mistake but how I can evaluate $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} f(z)/z$?

Comment: If $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z}$, can you evaluate $g(re^{i\theta})$?

Comment: No, not really, sorry. I don't know where $re^{i\theta}$ comes from.

Comment: It doesn't come from anything specific; it's unnecessary. Instead, it's a device that helps when finding limits at the origin (because it separates modulus from argument). In this case, since you're told the limit doesn't exist, you can also try to calculate partial limits along different curves (lines through the origin; in other cases where that doesn't work, you might try parabolas, etc.)

Comment: Puh, okay. I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. So I have to compute the limit $\lim\limits_{r\to0} \frac{f(re^{i\theta})}{\vert re^{i\theta}\vert}$ right?

Comment: Without the absolute value in the denominator; but yes, that's the easiest way, I think.

Comment: @jacmeird: Are you allowed to use the CR equations in polar coordinates? In Cartesian coordinates it is easy to see that they would require a lot of work - too much in fact for a lazy person like me.

Comment: @AlexM. I don't know. We never used them before.

Comment: @AlexM. I looked up the CR-E in polar coordinates and we definitely haven't used this in the lecture yet, so I'm not allowed to use them.

Comment: We talked about the following theorem: $f$ is in $z_0$ differentiable $\Leftrightarrow \exists\lim\limits{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} \Leftrightarrow f$ is $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable and the CR-E are valid. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is differentiable in $0$. There exists then a continuous $\Delta$ defined around $0$ such that $\dfrac {z^5} {|z|^4} = z \Delta (z)$, which for $z \ne 0$ is equivalent to $\dfrac {z^4} {|z|^4} = \Delta (z)$. Let us show that this $\Delta$ is not continuous in $0$, as it should.

If $\Delta$ were continuous in $0$, then we would be able to speak about $\lim \limits _{z \to 0} \Delta (z)$. But, on the one hand,

$$\lim _{z \to 0} \Delta (z) = \lim _{x \to 0, x > 0} \frac {x^4} {|x|^4} = \lim _{x \to 0, x > 0} \frac {x^4} {x^4} = 1$$

and, on the other hand, if $r$ is a *primitive* root of $x^8 + 1 = 0$,

$$\lim _{z \to 0} \Delta (z) = \lim _{rx \to 0, x > 0} \frac {(r x)^4} {|r x|^4} = \lim _{x \to 0, x > 0} \frac {r^4 x^4} {x^4} = r^4 = -1$$

which shows that $\Delta$ does not have a limit in $0$, therefore cannot be continuous there.

To show that $f$ admits partial derivatives in $0$ we just use the definition.

$$\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (0,0) = \lim _{x \to 0} \frac {f(x,0) - f(0,0)} {x-0} = \lim _{x \to 0} \frac {\frac {x^5} {|x|^4} - 0} x = \lim _{x \to 0} \frac {x^4} {|x|^4} = \lim _{x \to 0} \frac {x^4} {x^4} = 1 \\
\frac {\partial f} {\partial y} (0,0) = \lim _{y \to 0} \frac {f(0,y) - f(0,0)} {y-0} = \lim _{y \to 0} \frac {\frac {(\Bbb i y)^5} {|\Bbb i y|^4} - 0} y = \lim _{y \to 0} \frac {y^4} {|y|^4} \Bbb i ^5 = \lim _{y \to 0} \frac {y^4} {y^4} \Bbb i = \Bbb i.$$

Checking the Cauchy-Riemann equations in Cartesian coordinates is very annoying in this case (try it). It is much more convenient to use the following trick. If $\Re$ and $\Im$ denote the real and the imaginary part, and $f = u + \Bbb i v$, it is easy to show that

$$\frac {\partial u} {\partial x} (0,0) = \frac {\partial (\Re f)} {\partial x} (0,0) = \Re \left( \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (0,0) \right) = \Re (1) = 1 \\
\frac {\partial u} {\partial y} (0,0) = \frac {\partial (\Re f)} {\partial y} (0,0) = \Re \left( \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} (0,0) \right) = \Re (\Bbb i) = 0 \\
\frac {\partial v} {\partial x} (0,0) = \frac {\partial (\Im f)} {\partial x} (0,0) = \Im \left( \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (0,0) \right) = \Im (1) = 0 \\
\frac {\partial v} {\partial y} (0,0) = \frac {\partial (\Im f)} {\partial y} (0,0) = \Im \left( \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} (0,0) \right) = \Im (\Bbb i) = 1$$

from which it is easy to show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold at $0$.

But if the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold at a point, doesn't it mean that $f$ is $\Bbb C$-differentiable at that point? No, it doesn't, because $f$ is *not* $\Bbb R$-differentiable at $0$ - if it were, then the following limit would be $0$:

$$\lim _{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {f(x,y) - \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (0,0) (x-0) - \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} (0,0) (y-0)} {\| (x,y) \|} = \lim _{z \to 0} \frac {\frac {z^5} {|z|^4} - x - \Bbb i y} {|z|} = \lim _{z \to 0} \frac z {|z|} \left( \frac {z^4} {|z|^4} - 1 \right) .$$

Assuming that this limit exists, let us compute it along the trajectories $t \mapsto t$ and $t \mapsto rt$ with $r$ defined several paragraphs above and $t>0$:

$$\lim _{z \to 0} \frac z {|z|} \left( \frac {z^4} {|z|^4} - 1 \right) = \lim _{t \to 0, t>0} \frac t {|t|} \left( \frac {t^4} {|t|^4} - 1 \right) = 1 \cdot 0 = 0 \\
\lim _{z \to 0} \frac z {|z|} \left( \frac {z^4} {|z|^4} - 1 \right) = \lim _{rt \to 0, t>0} \frac {rt} {|rt|} \left( \frac {(rt)^4} {|rt|^4} - 1 \right) = r \cdot (r^4 - 1) = -2r$$

which shows that the limit does not exist, therefore $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, so one hypothesis needed for the equivalence between holomorphy and the Cauchy-Riemann equations is not satisfied, therefore there is no contradiction between the fact that $f$ is not $\Bbb C$-differentiable at $0$ and the fact that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at $0$.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! One question: Why do you use the root $r$ in the limit? Where do you get this? And why one don't have to proof the limit for $x<0$?

Comment: @jacmeird: My idea was to compute the limit along a line, so that should be $t \mapsto rt$. Next, I wanted to get rid of $\dfrac {t^4} {|t|^4}$, so the simplest choice was to take $t > 0$. The limit then reduces to $\dfrac {r^4} {|r|^4}$. For simplicity I wanted $r$ to have $|r|=1$, and I wanted to find a $r$ such that $r^4 \ne 1$ (because I had already obtained $1$ on a different trajectory). Therefore, it was simplest to require $r^4 = -1$ and this gave me the idea of a primitive root of $z^8 + 1 = 0$. This is not the only option, of course, any $r$ with $\dfrac {r^4} {|r|^4} \ne 1$ is good.

Comment: Is there a mistake in the second limit of the partial derivate? Where is the $\mathbb{i}$ in the denominator?

Comment: @jacmeird: $|\Bbb i| = 1$.

Comment: Ahh, stupid sorry. The last question: why is the partial derivate $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ not negative, because I learned the DE with $u_y=-v_y$.

Comment: @jacmeird: The CR equations say $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$. In our case this means $1 = 1$ and $0 = -0$ which are both true.